# Using percentile as measure in SSAS

Tags: ssas

How do I use percentile (let's say 99% percentile) as a measure in SSAS cube? I'd like to be able to report on it using many different dimensions and filters so pre-calculating in sql is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to evaluate percentiles over a dimension, then you can do it without having to pre-calculate anything in SQL. This can be done using a combination of the [TopPercent](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145498.aspx) and [Tail](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146056.aspx) MDX functions.

For example, say you want to find the 25th percentile over a [Date].[Calendar Month] dimension attribute by the [Measures].[Avg Daily Census] (I work in health care) measure. You could use the following query to do this.

```
WITH
   MEMBER [Measures].[25th Percentile] AS
      (
         Tail(
            TopPercent(
               [Date].[Calendar Month].[Calendar Month],
               100 - 25,
               [Measures].[Avg Daily Census]
            )
         ).Item(0),
         [Measures].[Avg Daily Census]
      )
SELECT 
   [Measures].[25th Percentile] ON 0
FROM [Census]
```

This query uses TopPercent to find the top 75 percent of values along the [Calendar Month] dimension attribute, finds the member with the lowest value along that set, and then evaluates the measure at that member.

Now, if you want to generate the entire set of percentile values, you can use a sequence utility dimension (just a dimension containing numbers), or you could create a custom percentile dimension containing 0-99. The following query would generate the values of the measure over all percentages.

```
WITH
   MEMBER [Measures].[Percentile] AS
      (
         Tail(
            TopPercent(
               [Date].[Calendar Month].[Calendar Month],
               100 - [Sequence].[Ones].CurrentMember.MemberValue,
               [Measures].[Avg Daily Census]
            )
         ).Item(0),
         [Measures].[Avg Daily Census]
      )
SELECT 
   [Measures].[Percentile] ON 0,
   [Sequence].[Ones].&[0] : [Sequence].[Ones].&[99] ON 1
FROM [Census]
```

However, if you are trying to evaluate percentiles at the grain of the fact table, then I believe you will either need to pre-calculate the percentile values for each fact row or add a [degenerate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_dimension) dimension and use the method above.